# namedtuple takes 3 arguments?

Tags: python, python-3.x, namedtuple

Attempting to run this code in Python3 Jupyter notebook :

```
t = namedtuple('a', 'b')
a = [1,0,1]
b = [1,1,1]
Out, In = np.asanyarray(a), np.asanyarray(b)
t(Out.shape[0], *In.shape)
```

returns error :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-151-7955ff03a60d> in <module>()
      3 b = [1,1,1]
      4 Out, In = np.asanyarray(a), np.asanyarray(b)
----> 5 t(Out.shape[0], *In.shape)

TypeError: __new__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Is possible to create namedtuple with two arguments ?

Update :

Why does this not cause similar issue :

```
t = namedtuple('ps', 'Out In S')

a = np.asanyarray([[1]])
b  = np.asanyarray([[1]])

d = t(a.shape[0], *b.shape)

d
```

computes :

```
ps(Out=1, In=1, S=1)
```

Update 2 :

Think i understand now `namedtuple('ps', 'Out In S')` translates to `namedtuple('name_of_tuple', 'tuple_values_seperated_by_spaces')`

Comment: The first argument of named tuple, is the name of the named tuple, not the arguments.

Comment: You are using the `namedtuple` incorrectly. [Check the docs on what the parameters should be](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first argument of named tuple constructor, is the `typename`: the name of the named tuple, not the arguments. [[documentation]](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)

So you should construct `t` as:

```
#                   v parameters
t = namedtuple('t', ('a', 'b'))
#              ^ type name
```

To make it more convenient, you can also provide a *space separated* string of parameters. So an equivalent one is:

```
#t = namedtuple('t', 'a b')
#                    ^ space separated list of parameters
```